# Having Angular and PHP server in same port

Tags: php, angular, session, xampp, port

I'm making a web service with Angular10 for the front-end and PHP and MySQL for the back-end. Since the way that Angular interacts with backend (or at least the one I've seen, I'm new with Angular) is with http requests, our PHP back-end works pretty much like an API. We're using XAMPP so the Apache server listens on the same route where all the files are, that way Angular makes a http request to localhost/myphpfile.php and gets the results in JSON.

So far so good, but we're trying to implement a login and a session system and we're clueless, as I have discovered doing some research that PHP $_SESSION resets itself whenever we "enter" and "leave" the .php file. It looks like what we have to do to make a session with Angular and PHP is to make them both listen to the same port. The problem is, if you try to make PHP server listen to port 4200 it will throw an error because that port is already on use, so we have no idea how are we supposed to implement a session system with both technologies.

Any ideas?

UPDATE: I'm going to write some more info that I've shared in the answers so it's more clear.

Apache server runs on port 80 or 443, and Angular runs on port 4200. The way I navigate through the website is with localhost:4200/view (with respective routing with Angular), and if I need any data from the DB, from Angular I make a http request to localhost/myphpfile.php which manages the connection to the DB and fetches the data, returning it in JSON so Angular can get it via .suscribe().

This is the PHP file path:

[image: This is the php file path]

The process we made was the following one:

1. The global variables "userid" and "logged" are null and false respectively
2. User goes to login and enters valid data
3. Angular sends a http request to login.php which verifies that the user and pass are correct. If so, it fetches the id from the users table and sets userid to that number, and also sets logged to true.
4. Once done this, those global variables are set into $_SESSION (this is done in setSession.php) -- so far we did an echo with $_SESSION and the result was correct
5. Then in the index*, we make a http request to getSession.php which checks whether $_SESSION is set or it's empty. If it's set, it sets the global variables to the content within $_SESSION. When we get to this point, $_SESSION was empty and didn't have the previous data.

*Global vars maintain their value as long as the user navigates through the web with the buttons, but if he navigates through URL instead, these variables will be emptied, that's why we need to set them again with $_SESSION

Getting those results made us search for the error and what we found was that both Apache and Angular need to be listening to the same port, hence this post.

Comment: _PHP $_SESSION resets itself whenever we "enter" and "leave" the .php file_ no, add `session_start` on the top of the file and the session will continue till the browser window is open. To integrate angular with php I suggest you to have a look at apache reverse proxy: so you will have a url on your domain with the 80 or 443 port (managed by apache) that will proxy what is inside the angular server on a different port. `domain/angular` that will forward to `angular:4200`.

Comment: you cannot use php session directly in angular but you can call your angular app from php with a flag that is true if on php the session is established or not.

Comment: Yeah we use session_start but since Apache server is on port 80 or 443 and Angular is on port 4200, the session is not mantained.

I kinda get what you're saying but I'm still missing a bit. Currently, I access the different views of the web with localhost:4200/view, and whenever I need some data from the DB I make a http request to localhost/myphpfile.php (should be on port 80 or 443).

So what you say is whenever I make a request, it should go to localhost/whatev/myphpfile.php which redirects to localhost/myphpfile.php or did I get it wrong?

Comment: From what you've described, that setup should not be an issue for sessions. What port you run on has no bearing on the sessions. As long as the session cookie are passed with the request, PHP will have it. If sessions doesn't work, you can do a simple test, like create a file that only sets a session value with the time() if it isn't already set and then output the value. If the time changes on each request, then post the code here (both js and php) so we can debug that. If it however doesn't change, then sessions works properly. Currently we don't have much to go on.

Comment: @Magnus: “What port you run on has no bearing on the sessions” - this is not true really. Session cookies aren’t shared between two different domains.

Comment: @MikeOne - Regardless what port you've configured on your web server to listen to, sessions will still work as long as the session cookie is passed with the request. I didn't mention different domains (or different ports) between the requests during the same session (since it wouldn't make much sense to have it like that).

Comment: But that seems to be what the OP is describing. Running angular on 4200 en php on 80/443..? Or did I misunderstand?

Comment: Yes, that's their setup, but the calls between the UI (angular) and PHP will always happen on the same port (80 or 443, depending on their code/setup) and from the same host (localhost:4200). Unless they randomly switch the port for angular (4200) between the requests, it will have the same host/port and will be able to read the same cookie.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same sort of setup in my environment. Note that there is a development part and a production part.

My development PHP server running on port 80 and my angular ng-server running on port 4200

## Co-habitation

The part about being on the same port...

### Development

When developing, I use the `ng serve`, but with some extra options:

`ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --proxy-config proxy.config.json`

#### proxy.config.json:

```
{
    "/api/*":{
        "target": "https://localhost",
        "secure": false,
        "changeOrigin": true,
        "logLevel":"debug"
    },
    "/auth/*":{
        "target": "https://localhost",
        "secure": false,
        "changeOrigin": true,
        "logLevel":"debug"
    }
}
```

Everything in my php project is either mapped to `/api/*`, or `/auth/*` or exists in that directory.

In my `.htaccess` file in my php project, I set up the errorhandlers or redirects to fit the angular project and my php. **Choose 1 of these approaches**:

#### .htaccess with RewriteEngine

```
RewriteEngine on
# angular rules
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^(.*) /index.html [NC,L]

#php rules for nice urls
RewriteRule ^api/(.+)/  /api.php?service=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^auth/login/$  /login.php [NC,L]
```

#### .htaccess with redirects

```
#redirect 400 and 404 errors to angular
ErrorDocument 400 index.html
ErrorDocument 404 index.html
```

### Production

When I have packaged my angular application for prod, I deploy it in the same root directory as my php application, and serve it all on the same server and port.

## Session handling

Let's say you have a `login.php` mapped to `/auth/login/` which creates a token, either in the form of a [jwt](/questions/tagged/jwt), or a [cookie](/questions/tagged/cookie).

You need to write logic that includes that token in all cals from your angular to your php. In other words, each of your php files, e.g. `api.php` needs to verify it at the start, and act accordingly. There are several ways to do this, I have chosen to go with jwts, and let the routes in angular have guards that restrict, based on the scopes in the JWT.